# How to load address column into a SQL Server database using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

The flat file data will be like this comma-separated values:

```
ID,Address,Name
1,#43,6th Cross, Cauvery layout,America-45,Kamlesh
```

Comment: you need to enclose the values between double quotes, otherwise you will never know when the 3rd one starts, or if you dont have that luxury, and its always the same number of commas ignore the header and load into a staging table, then write sql to fix up after

Comment: This is not a free coding service. You have "good knowledge in SSIS" so i suggest you just get on with the task. The first is to determine if the format of your source file can be changed to accurately reflect the information contained within. If not, you will need to write some logic to differentiate the address with the name since your fields are not really CSV (because they contain commas).